# How do I embed a change image tag just right at the bottom of a picture on hover?

Tags: css

Have you noticed facebook's profile picture has this *change profile picture* on hover at the lowest part of the image?

[image]

It's like this example but it has the user's name instead.

I have this but it looks pretty nasty.

HTML

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="./data/picture_caption/{{picture_caption}}" alt="polaroid" />
  <p class="label">This image looks super neat.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 257px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;


  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image:hover .label {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: wait ill update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here following is your edited code. It will display name from bottom on hover.

```css
.image {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.label {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition:0.1s all;
}

.image:hover .label {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLiJy.png" alt="polaroid" />
  <p class="label">Name</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, it's a bit rudimentary but it works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEmGJv

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://blog.ramboll.com/fehmarnbelt/wp-content/themes/ramboll2/images/profile-img.jpg" alt="Profile">
  <span class="img-txt">User name</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-container{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img-container img{
  display:block;
}


.img-txt{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  display:none;
}

.img-container:hover .img-txt{
  display:block;
}
```